# (WOULD) + past habit?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

From a lesson named (WOULD as a past tense), I quote the following:

[You cannot use WOULD for a past state or things that lasted a long time. 
"I USED TO smoke" that's correct, but you cannot say "I WOULD smoke"]. 
(end of quotation)

My question is: (smoke) is an action verb (not stative) refers to a past habit; why it can't be used with "WOULD" as stated above in the example given.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to refer the habit *in general,* you use 'used to'. And, you know that!

> I used to smoke (smoking was my habit/addiction in the past)

And, you can *also* use *would* to show habit. But then, it would be specific.

> He would smoke when in depression

So, when you use *would,* it may require more context, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

"Would" has a range of meanings, and in a simple sentence

> I would smoke

is ambiguous. The likely meaning is a conditional

> I would smoke (if I had matches)

But given the right context, you can get the past habit sense

> Every morning, John would smoke his pipe in the garden.

On the other hand "used to" only has one meaning. So a sentence with "used to" will be less ambiguous